# How to pass parameter to translated validation error message

Tags: validation, symfony, internationalization, translation

In Symfony2, [you can translate your validation error messages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages):

**Validation File**

```
# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: { message: "author.name.not_blank" }
```

**Translation File**

```
# validators.en.yml
author.name.not_blank: Please enter an author name.
```

But how can I pass a parameter to the translation file, if e.g. I want to pass the required min or max length?

```
author.name.min_length: "Required length: %limit% characters."
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about,

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: { message: "author.name.not_blank" }
            - Length:
                min: 3
                minMessage: "author.name.min_length"
```

While your translation file should contain,

```
# validators.en.yml
author.name.not_blank: Please enter an author name.
author.name.min_length: "Required length: {{ limit }} characters."
```

The `{{ limit }}` placeholder here will then fit the `min` pamarater of the length constraint.

Comment: the same approach doesn't work when messages are in Entity annotations (symfony 2.3)